# Jquery DataTable Searching and column Sorting not working in spring mvc project

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, datatables

I am using JQuery DataTable(3.2.1) for my spring mvc project.
But problem is that after clicking column header data is not change.
Here is my javascript Code :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "processing": true,
                    "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 75, 100],
                    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                    "paging": true,
                    "searchable": true,
                    "sortable": true,

                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "forum",
                        "type": "POST"
                    }

                });
            }
            );
```

But I have seen that, after every click on column header and after inserting any single character in search box, my controller retrieve same data again and again and send to view page.
Why not sorting data found and why not only matching data found.
Please help me to find out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes !.
I solved it.
In server side, I get the the client side column number,order and search string.
Then I execute my query using these parameters.

```
Integer columnNumber = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("order[0][column]"));
String order= request.getParameter("order[0][dir]");
String searchString= request.getParameter("search[value]");
```